# what is the best framework for web application development using java

Tags: jsp, web-applications, frameworks

Among the frameworks struts,spring web mvc,spring web MVC and hibernate,which is most suitable framework for web application development using jsp?

Comment: This is a tool-recommendation question, and off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest spring web MVC because it offers you a clean vision about your project and i would say it easier to use( of course it depends). Anyway, try read this for more arguments:

http://orangeslate.com/2006/11/10/12-benefits-of-spring-mvc-over-struts/

http://www.cygnet-infotech.com/blog/struts-2-vs-springmvc